# Cavity method pedagogic references

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, spin-models

I am looking for pedagogic references (textbook, review/expository articles, lecture notes, etc.) explaining the cavity method in detail.

I am talking specifically about this:

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1022221005097

and applications into algorithmic or many other areas that have arised from this method.

I have read this book:

Mezard, Marc, and Andrea Montanari. Information, physics, and computation. Oxford University Press, 2009.

but the presentation is sometimes too mathematical and notationally heavy. I am just looking for complementary references.